# Strtok - reading empty string at end of line

Tags: c, strtok

In my code below I use strtok to parse a line of code from a file that looks like:

```
1023.89,863.19  1001.05,861.94  996.44,945.67   1019.28,946.92  1023.89,863.19
```

As the file can have lines of different lengths I don't use fscanf. The code below works of except for one small glitch. It loops around one time too many and reads in a long empty string "        " before looping again recognizing the null token "" and exiting the while loop. I don't know why this could be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
fgets(line, sizeof(line), some_file);    
while ((line != OPC_NIL) {
    token = strtok(line, "\t"); //Pull the string apart into tokens using the commas
    input = op_prg_list_create();
    while (token != NULL) {
        test_token = strdup(token);
        if (op_prg_list_size(input) == 0)       
            op_prg_list_insert(input,test_token,OPC_LISTPOS_HEAD);  
        else
            op_prg_list_insert(input,test_token,OPC_LISTPOS_TAIL);
        token = strtok (NULL, "\t");
    }
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), some_file);                
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use the correct list of delimiters. Your code contradicts comments:

```
token = strtok(line, "\t"); //Pull the string apart into tokens using the commas
```

If you want to separate tokens by commas, use `","` instead of `"\t"`. In addition, you certainly don't want the tokens to contain the newline character `\n` (which appears at the end of each line read from file by `fgets`). So add the newline character to the list of delimiters:

```
token = strtok(line, ",\n"); //Pull the string apart into tokens using the commas
...
token = strtok (NULL, ",\n");
```

You might want to add the space character to the list of delimiters too (is `863.19 1001.05` a single token or two tokens? Do you want to remove spaces at end of line?).

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `sizeof(line)` tells me that `line` is a fixed size array living on the stack. In this case, `(line != OPC_NIL)` will never be `false`. However, `fgets()` will return `NULL` when the end of file is reached or some other error occurs. Your outer while loop should be rewritten as:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), some_file)) {
...
}
```

Your input file likely also has a newline character at the end of the last input line resulting in a single blank line at the end. This is the difference between this:

```
1023.89,863.19 1001.05,861.94 996.44,945.67 1019.28,946.92 1023.89,863.19↵
<blank line>
```

and this:

```
1023.89,863.19 1001.05,861.94 996.44,945.67 1019.28,946.92 1023.89,863.19
```

The first thing you should do in the while loop is check that the string is actually in the format you expect. If it's not then break:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), some_file)) {
    if(strlen(line) == 0) // or other checks such as "contains tab characters"
        break;
    ...
}
```